# how to show text in center in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Could you please tell me how to show text in center in highcharts .I want to show `A/B` value in center of both donut chart .I want to show 
value of donut chart `155/165` value in center here is my code

http://jsfiddle.net/oupmgvjy/12/

expected output

`A/B` value in center

```
$(function() {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'pie'
        },

        credits: {
         enabled: false
        },
        exporting: { enabled: false },
        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            layout: 'vertical',
            x: 0,
            y: 100,
                labelFormatter: function() {

                    return '<span style="color:' + this.color + ';background:red!important">' + this.name + ':</span> <b>' + this.y + '</b> </n>';
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Total percent market share'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
               series: {
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
            },
                allowPointSelect: false,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                showInLegend: true,
                dataLabels: {
                    format: '<b>{point.y}</b>',

                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: 'white'
                    }
                },

                startAngle: 0,
                endAngle: 270,
                center: ['50%', '75%']
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false,
            shadow: false
        },
        series: [{
         states: {hover: {enabled: false}},
          showInLegend: false,
            name: 'election result',
            enabled: true,
               dataLabels: {
                   enabled: true
                },
            data: [
                ['A', 155],
                ['B', 165],

            ],
            size: '30%',
            innerSize: '70%',
        }, {
        states: {hover: {enabled: false}},
            name: 'Versions',
            data: [
                ['sdsd', 55],
                ['sdf', 65],
                ['sdf', 65],
                ['sdf', 132],

            ],
            size: '70%',
            innerSize: '80%',

        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dataLabels.distance](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cpie%3E.dataLabels.distance) property to set the labels inside the pie.

```
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    distance: -40
  },
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/oupmgvjy/13/